# Importing styles in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style-manager

Is it possible to import styles in ArcMap?

Background:

We made a workflow in FME where CAD files are written to shapes and sld's which can be loaded in QGIS. This way we can view CAD data in QGIS as it was drawn in CAD. This really bridges the CAD - GIS gap.

Now we want to deploy this data AND styling to ArcGIS Online. After some digging around I think I understand how styling in ArcMap works:

- Define style in style library.
- Link style to featureclass.

Because it is designed this way it might be hard to import styles like I do in QGIS. I wonder if someone has worked around this challenge? We're talking about a serious bunch of cad files from all types of file owners. So no default styling / layers / etc.

The best alternatives I can think of:

- WMS QGIS Server for style combined with featureservice for vector.
- Generating tiles with QGIS QTile and upload to AGOL.
- Generating raster with FME and tile with ArcMap.

But I would like to only use a featureservice.

---

Update 201610006:
Tiles are out of the question because of processing time and storage.

The logic step is to map the featureclasses to company standards with standard styles but that is not bridging the CAD-GIS gap.

Brainstorming about this we see another possibility: Writing to service definition file (zip with json) and edit this one before uploading. SDF contains data AND styling. I think it might be a long shot and deep dive in json but with FME everything is possible. The downside is the possibility ESRI closing this door after reading my posts about it.

Comment: As far as I know It's not possible. You can't even save the ArcMap CAD renderrer as a layer file and apply it to a geodatabase feature class. (The renderrer uses 3 required CAD files, line weight etc. which approximates the look of the drawing in ArcMap) The style file in ArcMap is really an ms access database. change .style to .mdb and have a look. All this will change in Pro i believe so you may have a better luck trying that route.  Haven't tried working with CAD files in pro yet but the renderrer is new and so is the way symbology is deployed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And for the style / mdb tip! I'm gonna check out Pro for sure. Will give feedback.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible to publish from Pro to AGOL... https://geonet.esri.com/thread/117751

Comment: Have you considered assigning subtypes?  You can control symbology that way and FME can read and write subtypes.  Check out this article:  https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/886/working-with-geodatabase-subtypes-and-domains.html

Comment: That is a promising alternative. I must admit that we found a (bit complex but dynamic) way to do this but don't dare to post the solution here as the folks at E$RI might close the route.